# Shortcode not working on Wordpress under Paragraph tag

Tags: wordpress

I am using Shortcode for my wordpress website. That code is working fine. But does not work on p tag. E.g

```
    [box type=”shadow”]<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>[/box]
```

Here is my code

```
function boxShow($atts, $content = null ){
    //default values
    $option = shortcode_atts( array(
    'type' => '',
    ), $atts );

    ob_start(); 

    $class = $option[ 'type' ] ? str_replace( '"', '', $option[ 'type' ] ) : 'normal';

    //HTML goes here
    ?>
    <div class="box <?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content; ?></div>

    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'box', 'boxShow' );
```

Comment: can you tell me which editor are you using block editor or classic editor?

Answer (score 0):

You Should use the shortcode as follows:

```
[box type=shadow]<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>[/box]
```

And Change your code as

```
function boxShow($atts, $content = null ){

    $option = shortcode_atts( array(
    'type' => '',
    ), $atts );




    $class = $option[ 'type' ] ? str_replace( '"', '', $option[ 'type' ] ) : 'normal';


    $output = '<div class="box '.$class.'">'.$content.'</div>';

    return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'box', 'boxShow' );
```